# python lint error if not implementing interface

Tags: python, lint, pylint, flake8

I know python likes to play it nice and loose with types, but sometimes you want a plugin type interface, and want to discover before production that someone has missed something.   I found abcmeta - so did the following:

```py
class Abstract_Base(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def a():
        pass
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def b():
        pass

class Inheritor_One(Abstract_Base):
    def a():
        pass
```

but when I do python -m flake8.... it has no problem with that.   Is there any way of writing it such that someone not overriding an abstract method will go bang at linting time?

Comment: as written that isn't necessarily an error -- you've just defined *another* abstract class.  it's only an error upon construction.  asking for tool suggestions is off topic on SO as it tends to lead to advertisery/spammy answers (I can think of at least 2 such tools which _could_ produce an error here -- you've actually tagged one of them(???))

Answer (score 0):

[Pylint](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/) raises `abstract-method` for your example:

```
W0223: Method 'b' is abstract in class 'Abstract_Base' but is not overridden (abstract-method)
```

If you actually want `Inheritor_One` to be an abstract class you can disable the warning locally in this class and still have the warning when you use the abstract class later on:

```py
import abc


class Abstract_Base(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def a(self):
        pass
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def b(self):
        pass

class Inheritor_One(Abstract_Base):
    # pylint: disable=abstract-method
    def a(self):
        pass
```

Comment: thanks - I was using pyflake8, which I thought included pylint - but I guess not.. am adding pylint to my build.